# How to print a simple HTML table with QWebView and QPrinter without cutting off the right side?

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit, qwebview, qprinter

Since my update from Qt 4.7.4 to Qt 4.8.7 it isn't possible for me to print a simple HTML table without cutting off the right side. Here is my PySide code that shows the table in the QPrintPreviewDialog (the issue is not related to PySide or PyQt and you can reproduce it with C++ and Qt):

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

webView = QWebView()            
webView.load(QtCore.QUrl('table.html'))

printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
printer.setPaperSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A4)

printPreview = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(printer)    
printPreview.paintRequested.connect(webView.print_)

#Avoid blank preview on startup                    
QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

printPreview.show()        
app.exec_()
```

And here is the HTML code of my simple table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
    <style>
        table {
            width:100%;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        table, td, tr, th{
            border:0.091em solid grey;                 
        }                        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>ENDENAME</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>    
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>ENDE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the issue with Qt 4.8.7]

As you can see, the right side of the table is missing.

With Qt 4.7.4 the result was correct, here is a screenshot:

[image: Same code and WORKING HTML table with Qt 4.7.4]

I tried to investigate the issue by myself. And I found out, that if the ratio between printer.pageRect().size().width() and webView.page().mainFrame().contentsSize().width() is below 0.5 the cutting occurs (at 96 DPI for printer and screen). If the DPI value is different, then you have to convert both values to inch for the correct ratio.

```
    contentSize = webView.page().mainFrame().contentsSize().width()        
    pageSize = printer.pageRect().size().width()

    pageWidthNorm = float(pageWidth)/float(printer.resolution())
    contentWidthNorm = contentSize.width() / horizontalDpi

    #Cutting off at 0.5     
    magicFactor = float(pageWidthNorm)/float(contentWidthNorm)
```

However, I'm not able to solve this issue with this information. I tried to set this magicFactor as the zoomFactor for the QWebView and it works. But the result is very ugly and not what I want.

I hope someone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: I tested it with PyQt4.11.4 and I see the same behavior. Might be a problem of Qt4.X then. Btw. very well written question. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: @Trilarion I tried the same example with Qt 4.8.7 on C++ and there was the same problem! So, yes, the issue is NOT related to PyQt or PySide. It's a Qt problem. My upgrade from PySide 1.1.1 to 1.2.4 changed my Qt version from 4.7.4 to Qt 4.8.7. An according to the Qt changelog, they also upgrades QtWebkit from 1.x to 2.2.2. So in short, there is some strange bug in QtWebkit 2.2.2. Unfortunately Qt 4.8.7 was the last version of Qt 4, so I need some sort of workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
def handlePrint(self):
    dialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog()
    if dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())


def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
    html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
    <style>
        table {
            width:100%;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        table, td, tr, th{
            border:0.091em solid grey;                 
        }                        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>ENDENAME</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>    
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>ENDE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
"""
    web_view = QWebView()
    web_view.setHtml(html)
    web_view.print_(printer)
```